# Yii2 конструкторы в компонентах

Tags: yii2

Для чего документация по `Yii2` рекомендует: Если вы переопределяете конструктор, то добавьте последним аргументом параметр $config и затем передайте его в конструктор предка. В чем необходимость этого шага и что конкретно в этом параметре требуется передать.

пример:

```
class MyClass extended Component
    public $config;
    public $params;

    private $value1;
    private $value2;

    public $search;

    public function __construct($search, $config = [])
    {
        this->$search = $search

        this->value1 = someFunction1($search);
        this->value2 = someFunction2($search);

        parent::__construct($config);
    }
```

Для чего конретно тут передавать какой то параметр в родительский конструктор?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы компоненты могли вызываться с набором предопределенных свойств, которые, как раз, передаются в `$config`, а `parent::__construct` их устанавливает.

Т.е. `$config = ['search'=>1];`, и свойство `$search` класса `MyClass` будет равно 1 после вызова `parent::__construct`.

Соответственно, если `$this->search = $search` поставить после вызова родительского конструктора, то свойство `$search` будет всегда определяться аргументом `$search`. Однако, в PHP не рекомендуется переопределять методы так, чтобы набор аргументов у родителя и потомка отличался.